# How to keep the initial value a pointer was pointing after a variable is changed?

Tags: c++, pointers

I realize this code is silly, but it is a simplified version of my problem. The code below prints out 10 10's, what I would like it to do is print out the numbers 0 through 9, which were the values j was pointing at when j was added to the vector. How can I keep the pointer stored in the vector pointing to the original integer value it was pointing to when it was stored?

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int*> test;
    int *j;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        j = &i;
        test.push_back(j);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        std::cout << *test[i] << std::endl;
    }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are incorrect. All the elements in `test` point to the `i` from the previous loop, which doesn't exist anymore. It's undefined behavior and it's incorrect to assume that they point to the value 10.

Comment: If you want to take the *value* of an object then just don't use pointers. A `std::vector<int>` would do exactly what you want. Using a pointer is going out of your way to not do what you want.

Comment: Why do you want `std::vector<int*>` and not simply `std::vector<int>`?

Comment: If you only record the location of a variable, you will get whatever's there at the time you read it.  If you want to preserve the value that is at that location, you don't want to store the location at all, but the value.  Don't store a pointer to an int, store the int itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this simple example pointers aren't even necessary! We can simply do

```
std::vector<int> test;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    test.push_back(i);
}
```

---

However, if you insist on using pointers like you are...you currently have **Undefined Behavior**.

After the loop ends, `i` goes out of scope and your pointers are pointing to memory you no longer own. What you want can be accomplished by using dynamically allocated memory. We can allocate a new integer for each value of the vector:

```
std::vector<int*> test;
int *j;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    j = new int(i);
    test.push_back(j);
}
```

Just remember that you'll have to deallocate the memory yourself after you're done!

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    delete test.at(i);
}
```

Comment: Or you could use `std::iota`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I realized pointers are unnecessary here, that is what I meant when I said the code is silly, but I need to know how to handle such a situation using pointers so I can apply in a similar situation where it is hard to get around using them. The "new" operator seems to be what I need.

Comment: @Pete: This is rather old C++ code. In new C++, we mostly avoid `new`. Modern code would use `std::make_unique(i)`. This returns a _smart_ pointer, a `std::unique_ptr<int>` to be precise. The reason we use it is to avoid the `delete`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you're looking for this

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> test;
    int *j;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        j = &i;
        test.push_back(*j);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        std::cout << test[i] << std::endl;
    }
        return 0;
}
```

So.... I've changed 'test' to be a vector of integer values, not pointers, and I've dereferenced the pointer 'j' before storing it in the vector. And I've adjusted the print routine to print the value

Answer (score 1):

You can point to elements of another container:

```
std::vector<int*> test;  // holding pointers
std::array<int, 10> ray; // holding values
std::iota(ray.begin(), ray.end(), 0) // 0, 1, 2, 3..
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    int *j = &ray[i];
    test.push_back(j);
}
```